# Why is the squared term on sine higher than on cosine?

Tags: math-mode

In the following fraction, the square on the `sin` is formatted higher than it is on the `cos`:

```latex
\int\frac{-2\sin2\theta}{\sqrt{2\cos^2\theta}+\sqrt{2\sin^2\theta}}\,d\theta
```

[image: render 1]

The sine squared term also seems to bring up the height of the square root.

---

The following formula also has a similar issue:

```latex
\int\frac{\cos{\varphi}\left(1+\cfrac{2\sqrt{1-\sin^2{\varphi}}}{\sqrt{1-2\sin^2{\varphi}}}\right)}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2{\varphi}}+\sqrt{1-2\sin^2{\varphi}}}\,d\varphi
```

[image: render 2]

The sine terms really bring the height up to the point that it's using about a fifth of the paper once printed. I know I'm using `\cfrac` but this problem doesn't appear anywhere else unless there's a `\sqrt{\sin^2\varphi}` in it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please extend your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and add a screenshot of the result.

Comment: i is taller than o

Comment: May I suggest the alternative of just _not using_ the horribly inconsistent sin²φ notation? It's so much clearer to write (sin φ)² instead, `(\sin\varphi)^2`. — I know, sin² is standard but it makes no sense and clashes with sin⁻¹ which means something completely different.

Comment: @leftaroundabout On the other hand, `\sin^2` contains less parentheses and is thus easier to read. If `\sin^2` is a very common occurrence in a particular field, it doesn't hurt to simplify the notation to reduce overall expression complexity. Also, `\sin \circ \sin` is quite rare.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq in the cases where you have so many sins and cos' that the readability is a concern, the same argument can be made about these long three-letter symbols. Just make a quick definition s = sin φ; c = cos φ then, and only write s² and c² subsequently – _much_ more readable. (Or possibly `s_\varphi^2` / `c_\varphi^2`.)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I noticed the same problem when preparing my calculus lecture notes. What happens is that the superscript is placed with respect to the whole box containing “sin”, which is higher than “cos” and “tan” because of the tittle. I examined the possibility of smashing the “i”, but this would not work with `\sqrt{\sin x}`.

Thus my preference went to redefining `\cos` and `\tan` to be as high as `\sin`. You may need also the other goniometric functions, if you use them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\let\cos\relax % undefine \cos
\DeclareMathOperator{\cos}{cos\vphantom{\mathrm{i}}}
\let\tan\relax % undefine \tan
\DeclareMathOperator{\tan}{tan\vphantom{\mathrm{i}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\int\frac{-2\sin2\theta}{\sqrt{2\cos^2\theta}+\sqrt{2\sin^2\theta}}\,d\theta
\\[1ex]
\sqrt{\tan x}\sqrt{\sin x}\sqrt{\cos x}
\\[1ex]
\sqrt{1+\tan^2 x}\sqrt{1-\sin^2 x}\sqrt{1-\cos^2 x}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

An alternative you may find attractive is to smash everything and be confident in TeX's ability to avoid problems.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\let\cos\relax % undefine \cos
\DeclareMathOperator{\cos}{cos\vphantom{\mathrm{i}}}
\let\tan\relax % undefine \tan
\DeclareMathOperator{\tan}{tan\vphantom{\mathrm{i}}}

\DeclareMathOperator{\ssin}{\vphantom{x}\smash{\mathrm{sin}}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\scos}{\vphantom{x}\smash{\mathrm{cos}}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\stan}{\vphantom{x}\smash{\mathrm{tan}}}

\begin{document}

With the \verb|\vphantom| strategy
\begin{gather*}
\int\frac{-2\sin2\theta}{\sqrt{2\cos^2\theta}+\sqrt{2\sin^2\theta}}\,d\theta
\\[1ex]
\sqrt{\tan x}\sqrt{\sin x}\sqrt{\cos x}
\\[1ex]
\sqrt{1+\tan^2 x}\sqrt{1-\sin^2 x}\sqrt{1-\cos^2 x}
\end{gather*}

With the \verb|\smash| strategy
\begin{gather*}
\int\frac{-2\ssin2\theta}{\sqrt{2\scos^2\theta}+\sqrt{2\ssin^2\theta}}\,d\theta
\\[1ex]
\sqrt{\stan x}\sqrt{\ssin x}\sqrt{\scos x}
\\[1ex]
\sqrt{1+\stan^2 x}\sqrt{1-\ssin^2 x}\sqrt{1-\scos^2 x}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to pursue the `\smash` strategy, implement it as

```
\let\sin\relax \let\cos\relax \let\tan\relax
\DeclareMathOperator{\sin}{\vphantom{x}\smash{\mathrm{sin}}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\cos}{\vphantom{x}\smash{\mathrm{cos}}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\tan}{\vphantom{x}\smash{\mathrm{tan}}}
```

Answer (score 8):

As pointed out in the comments, this happens because "sin" is taller than "cos" because of the "i", so the exponent is raised a little bit. You could always `\smash` the `\sin` wherever you want to decrease the height of `\sin^2` to that of `\cos^2`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\smashedsin}{\smash{\sin}}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\int\frac{-2\sin2\theta}{\sqrt{2\cos^2\theta}+\sqrt{2\sin^2\theta}}\,d\theta
\qquad
\int\frac{-2\sin2\theta}{\sqrt{2\cos^2\theta}+\sqrt{2\smashedsin^2\theta}}\,d\theta \\[2mm]
\int\frac{\cos{\varphi}\left(1+\cfrac{2\sqrt{1-\sin^2{\varphi}}}{\sqrt{1-2\sin^2{\varphi}}}\right)}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2{\varphi}}+\sqrt{1-2\sin^2{\varphi}}}\,d\varphi
\qquad
\int\frac{\cos{\varphi}\left(1+\cfrac{2\sqrt{1-\smashedsin^2{\varphi}}}{\sqrt{1-2\smashedsin^2{\varphi}}}\right)}{\sqrt{1-\smashedsin^2{\varphi}}+\sqrt{1-2\smashedsin^2{\varphi}}}\,d\varphi
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I ended up combing the redefinition and `\smash` to make all functions inline and the same height.

```
    \let\sin\relax
    \DeclareMathOperator{\sin}{\smash{sin}}
    \let\tan\relax
    \DeclareMathOperator{\tan}{\smash{tan}}
    \let\arcsin\relax
    \DeclareMathOperator{\arcsin}{\smash{arcsin}}
    \let\arctan\relax
    \DeclareMathOperator{\arctan}{\smash{arctan}}
```

Comment: Have you tried it out? This uses *italic* fonts for the math operators. I seriously doubt that's intended.